# mi problema es que en mi proyecto de laravel no se ven refeljados los cambios que hice en el welcome, me paso luego de instalar laravel breeze

Tags: laravel

| Una cabecera | Otra cabecera |
| --- | --- |
| Primera | fila |
| Segunda | fila |

Comment: Te sugiero que hagas un [tour](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) y mires en la [ayuda](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help) para que veas como preguntar, cosas que debes evitar en las preguntas, etc. Aquí podrás ver [cómo preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)